# alembic/env.py target_metadata = metadata "No module name al_test.models"

Tags: alembic

When I use alembic to control the version of my project's database,part of codes in env.py 
like:

```
# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from al_test.models import metadata

target_metadata = metadata
```

when I run 'alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Added user table"', I get an error :
    File "alembic/env.py", line 18, in 
    from al_test.models import metadata
ImportError: No module named al_test.models

so how to solve the question? thanks!

Comment: Well, the meaning of the error is quite straightforward. alembic cannot find the model you refer to. I suggest you add to your question a description of your project layout, including al_test and the code underneath it. It could be a path issue, or it could be your packages/modules aren't structured correctly.

Comment: I checked my project structure some times, there is no mistake.So I'm confused.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a bit late, and you may have already figured out the issue, but my guess the problem is that your alembic/ directory is not part of the system path. I.e. you need to do something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path/to/al_test)

from al_test.models import metadata
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your env.py like this, to add the current working directory to the sys.path that Python uses when searching for modules:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from al_test.models import metadata
target_metadata = metadata
....
....
```